# Função Retorna [object Promise]

Tags: javascript

função que pega os dados de uma url:

```
const getDadosAsync = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let url = 'http://' + host + '/dados';
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      var data = xhttp.responseText;
      resolve(data);
    }
  }
  xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xhttp.send();
});
```

> O valor de data e algo parecido com:
>   teste,123mudar,IMPEXPROS,sarmento:172.20.1.1,172.20.1.2,172.20.1.3,172.20.1.4,172.20.1.5,172.20.1.6,255.255.255.0,192.168.1.1,192.168.1.140,255.255.255.0,192.168.1.121:

e pego os dados nessa função:

```
const texto1 =  async () =>{
  let dados = await getDadosAsync();

  let arrParams = dados.split(':');
  let nomes = arrParams[0].split(',');
  let ips = arrParams[1].split(',');
  let arrDados = [];

  arrDados.push({
   ssidAP: nomes[0],
   senhaAP: nomes[1],
   ssidSTA: nomes[2],
   senhaSTA: nomes[3],
   ipLocal: ips[0],
   ipmodulo1: ips[1],
   ipmodulo2: ips[2],
   ipmodulo3: ips[3],
   ipmodulo4: ips[4],
   ipmodulo5: ips[5],
   mascaraAP: ips[6],
   gatewaySTA: ips[7],
   localSTA: ips[8],
   mascaraSTA: ips[9],
   servidorSTA: ips[10],
 });

  let a = setSSIDAP();
  let b = setSSIDSTA();

  if (a == "null" && b == "null"){
    return "null";
  }
  if(b == "null" && a != "null"){
    return a + ","+ arrDados.ssidSTA + "," + arrDados.senhaSTA;
  }
  if(a == "null" && b != "null"){
    return arrDados.ssidAP + "," + arrDados.senhaAP + "," + b;
  }
  if (a != "null" && b != "null"){
    return a + b;
  }
}
```

edit1:
Recebo os dados dessa função da seguinte forma:

```
const sendConf = async () => {
    let users = setUsers();

    if (users){
        //let url = decodeURI("http://" + host + "/config?a=" + localreles + "&b=" + apwifi + "&c=" + ips +"&dd=null:&d=" + users.usuarios + "&e=" + users.senhas + "&f=" + users.tags + "&g=" + users.horarios);
        let url = decodeURI("http://"+host+"/config?a=null:&b="+texto1()+":&c="+texto2()+":&d=null:&e=" + users.usuarios + "&f=" + users.senhas + "&g=" + users.tags + "&h=" + users.horarios);
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                var data = xhttp.responseText;
                console.log(url);
                alert(url);

            }
        }
        await xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        await xhttp.send();
    }
}
```

e o retorno dessa função texto1() esta retornando [object Promise], porque nao os dados? Testei chamar texto1().then() e retornou a mesma coisa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando tens a palavra `async` na declaração de uma função ela vai retornar uma Promise cujo valor podes usar quando a Promise estiver resolvida.

Para usares o valor de `const texto1 =  async ()=>{` tens de usar o `.then(resultado => {` e dentro desse `then` então podes usar o valor que `resultado` possa conter.

```js
const fnAtrasada = async() => new Promise(res => {
  setTimeout(() => res('Olá'), 2000);
});
const fn = async(nome) => {
  console.log('Função iniciada...');
  const saudacao = await fnAtrasada();
  return `${saudacao} ${nome}!`;
}

fn('Ana').then(string => console.log(string));
```

Para usares vários dessa maneira tens de usar o `Promise.all`, onde passas uma array de promises, e dentro do `.then()` dele recebes uma array com o resultado de cada promise dento. Um exemplo seria assim:

```js
Promise.all([texto1(), texto2()]).then(resultados => {
  let url = decodeURI("http://" + host + "/config?a=null:&b=" + resultados[0] + ":&c=" + resultados[1] + ":&d=null:&e=" + users.usuarios + "&f=" + users.senhas + "&g=" + users.tags + "&h=" + users.horarios);
  // e o resto do ajax aqui...
});
```

Comment: Obrigado! deu certo!